# How do I retrieve a record with a minimum value

Tags: min

Have the following logic.
I can't understand why the query retrieves both '2',NY and 3,'MA' records
and not only the '2','NY' record.

```
create table dbo.DMDAddressCity
(
    AddressCd char(3),
    AddressCity varchar(20)
)
insert DMDAddressCity
select 'NY','New York'
insert DMDAddressCity
select 'MA','Boston'

create table dbo.DMDAddressPriority
(
    PriorityId tinyint NOT NULL,
    AddressCd char(3)
) 

insert DMDAddressPriority
select 1,'NJ'
insert DMDAddressPriority
select 2,'NY'
insert DMDAddressPriority
select 3,'MA'

select PR.PriorityId, PR.AddressCd
from DMDAddressPriority PR
join DMDAddressCity CT
on
    CT.AddressCd = PR.AddressCd 
where PriorityId = 
(
    select min(PriorityId)
    from DMDAddressPriority PR2
    where           
        --trim(PR.AddressCd) = trim(PR2.AddressCd)  
        PR.AddressCd = PR2.AddressCd 
)
```

I am looking to retrieve only 1 record that has the minimum priorityid.
Appreciate some guidance on what I am not doing right.

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Please tag your question with the implementation of SQL you're using as well as [tag:sql].

Answer (score 0):

Your subquery is referencing the outer query and finding the minimum priority where `PR.AddressCd = PR2.AddressCd`. Of course, the minimum `addresscd` for NY is 2 and the minimum `addresscd` for MA is 3, so they are both selected.

To get the minimum for the entire table, you don't need that `PR.AddressCd = PR2.AddressCd` condition in the subquery. However...

```
where PriorityId = 
(
    select min(PriorityId)
    from DMDAddressPriority PR2
)
```

... will not do what you want since it will get the absolute minimum in the table (1) which neither of your records match. You need to get the absolute minimum of the records you are considering. I suggest considering something more along the lines of:

```
WITH cte AS
(
 select PR.PriorityId, PR.AddressCd
 from DMDAddressPriority PR
 join DMDAddressCity CT
  on CT.AddressCd = PR.AddressCd
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE priority = (SELECT min(priorityid) FROM cte)
```

Or

```
SELECT PriorityId, AddressCd
FROM
(
 select PR.PriorityId, PR.AddressCd, min(PR.PriorityId) OVER() MinPriorityId
 from DMDAddressPriority PR
 join DMDAddressCity CT
  on CT.AddressCd = PR.AddressCd
)
WHERE PriorityId = MinPriorityId
```

Comment: Thank you EdmCoff.  If you don't mind clarifying...in the inner subquery I don't use a group by but merely join PR.AddressCd = PR2.AddressCd to keep only those records that match any possible criteria that could be used in the outer query. So shouldn't the min apply across the 2 records NY and MA and NOT attempt to group them?

Comment: In your attempt, the inner query gets evaluated for each outer row. It doesn't only get executed once. So when you are considering `AddressCd`='MA' in the outer query, the `PR.AddressCd = PR2.AddressCd` condition means the inner query is also limited to that, and so on.